# PHP vertical list from external content

Tags: php

I don't understand a thing about PHP but am trying to learn however I'm not able to move in the right direction in creating a vertical list:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') OR die('Restricted Area');
error_reporting(VIKBOOKING_ERROR_REPORTING);

$rooms=$this->rooms;
$category=$this->category;
$navig=$this->navig;

$currencysymb = vikbooking :: getCurrencySymb();

if(is_array($category)) {
    ?>
    <h3 class="vbclistheadt"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></h3>
    <?php
    if(strlen($category['descr']) > 0) {
        ?>
        <div class="vbcatdescr">
            <?php echo $category['descr']; ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}else {
    echo vikbooking :: getFullFrontTitle();
}

?>
<div class="vblistcontainer">
<ul class="vblist">
<?php
foreach($rooms as $r) {
    $carats = vikbooking::getRoomCaratOriz($r['idcarat']);
    //BEGIN: Joomla Content Plugins Rendering
    JPluginHelper::importPlugin('content');
    $myItem = &JTable::getInstance('content');
    $dispatcher = &JDispatcher::getInstance();
    $myItem->text = $r['smalldesc'];
    $dispatcher->trigger('onContentPrepare', array('com_vikbooking.roomslist',&$myItem, &$params, 0));
    $r['smalldesc']= $myItem->text;
    //END: Joomla Content Plugins Rendering
    ?>
```

I understand that &myItem->text loads the content into the $r['smalldesc'] which gets called further down the code on

```
<div class="vbrowcdescr"><?php echo $r['smalldesc']; ?></div>
```

I've tried some codes I found on the forum changing the variables to my code but I can't seem to get it working

I was using the following code

```
    $r['smalldesc'] = $textarea;
$items= explode(';', $textarea);
echo "<ul>\n";
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo "\t<li>", trim($item), "</li>\n";
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: what is vertical list? do you actually want to display some string in UL/OL tag?

Comment: Yes i was attempting with <li> and explode function

Comment: so? re-formulate your question to include your attempts, actual result and desired result of output

Comment: No, `$r['smalldesc']` is assigned to `$myItem->text`, so `$r` and `$r['smalldesc']` have to be defined. What is `$r`, a `$_POST` or `$_GET` array? If so you should have an HTML input with `name='smalldesc'` on your form. You should have a basic understanding of PHP to execute this code.

Comment: I think $r is not defined in this php file so it must be getting it from some other file. I've edited my question to include the beginning of the php.

Comment: As I said i don't know much about programming, $textarea was the code i added to try to figure this out, sorry :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope my telepathy works, try this code:

`$r['smalldesc'] = $myItem->text;` should be replaced with:

```
$items = explode(';', $myItem->text);
$r['smalldesc'] = '<ul>';
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $r['smalldesc'] .= '<li>' . trim($item) . '</li>';
$r['smalldesc'] .= '</ul>';
```

Comment: Your telepathy is good :P, it worked like a charm, now I need to go back and edit the CSS. Thanks a million ! I was close on my 10000 tries :)